# Realm returning wrong data

Tags: swift, realm

I'm new to realm. I have two objects, Restaurant and Address.

```
class Address: Object {

    @objc dynamic var identifier: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String!
    @objc dynamic var restaurant: Restaurant!
}
```

notice that Address has relationship with restaurant.

```
class Restaurant: Object {

    @objc dynamic var identifier: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String!
    @objc dynamic var location: String!
    @objc dynamic var images: String!
}
```

now on my api side I will request for addresses and it will return list of addresses with restaurant but the restaurant has an identifier value only and others are nil to save loading time. I will save it to my realm.

Now in order to get the other restaurant details like name and location etc. I will request again list of restaurants to the api and save it to realm.

Right now I got 2 list of records save on my database. **Address** with incomplete restaurant information and **Restaurants** with complete information.

Now I want to get the **Restaurant** with complete information using the identifier of the **Address.restaurant.identifier**. so the code is like this.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier = %i", address.restaurant.identifier)
let restaurant =  realm.objects(Restaurant.self).filter(predicate).first!
```

My expected output is the restaurant with complete details because I'm filtering the Restaurant class, instead I got the restaurant inside the **Address** object with incomplete restaurant details.

Could someone help me query the restaurant with complete details? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you make 2 requests, one for short addresses and another for restaurant details, in first request you make a relation between address and restaurant, but when you are getting restaurant details you save it like new object.

I think in your case you need to provide primaryKey for each class that you want to save in DB like:

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "identifier"
}
```

After that data from restaurant details request will update your restaurant with the same id in DB and there will be only one unique object.

Also, you can have 2 tables, one for restaurants and another for addresses. Address will have restaurants identifiers, restaurant will have only one address identifier.

Hope it help you

Comment: @AlvinJohn did it help?

Comment: yes. Also I changed the way I add objects to realm like this:
 realm.add(objects, update: true)

Answer (score 0):

From [Realm Swift documentation for relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships): "For example, rex.owner?.address.country will traverse the object graph and automatically fetch each object from Realm as needed."

So realm would fetch `Restaurant` object for `Address` object only when it is accessed. So I would not try to optimize fetches by having 2 `Restaurants` in the Realm database.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do a query?

Instead of doing:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier = %i", address.restaurant.identifier)
let restaurant =  realm.objects(Restaurant.self).filter(predicate).first!
```

Couldn't you just do (given that you have the `Address` object):

```
let restaurant = address.restaurant
```